# Can anyone identify this unknown plant

Tags: identification

I got it free and Have no idea what it is. Grows really fast. single stem, rounded leaves, 2 opposing leaves, spikes on stem below or above leaves

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

Comment: Hi Terry, are you able to photograph it with natural light?

Answer (score 15):

This is a [Kalanchoe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalanchoe) which has been grown under low light conditions. That is why there is a large distance between the leaves and why the white variegation on the edges of the leaves is so slight.

This might be a variegated [Kalanchoe Laciniata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalanchoe_laciniata) but it is hard to tell the variety due to the low light conditions in the picture.  This species grows up to 3 feet tall or about 1 meter but requires 6 to 8 hours of direct sun a day to be healthy.

Provide lots of light, water when dry and it may show it's greenish white flowers.